# docker-compose resets django db when requirements.txt change

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` to develop a django project with `postgres` db.

Using VS Code, I get two dockers running after `Docker Compose Up`.

Every time I work on the project, the db is intact

The issue is when any changes are made to `requirements.txt`, the db image resets, even though no changes were made to that image.

I have to run `python manage.py migrate` and `createsuperuser` and the db is empty.

I can understand that the `web` docker image must be recreated when there are changes to `requirements.txt`, but why does the db image resets?

Is there a way to avoid this? I would hate to publish the production app and not be able to install additional libs in newer versions without losing the db.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'aaa'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'bbb'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'ccc'
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

`settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ccc',
        'USER': 'aaa',
        'PASSWORD': 'bbb',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make persistent volume for your database, and store it somewhere on your host.
In example below - directory `database` in your `docker-compose.yml` directory.

1. Create `database` directory (`mkdir database`) next to `docker-compose.yml`
2. Edit your `docker-compose.yml` file:

   ```
   version: '3'

   services:
     db:
       image: postgres
       environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: 'aaa'
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'aaa'
         POSTGRES_DB: 'aaa'
       volumes:
         - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     web:
       build: .
       volumes:
         - .:/code
       ports:
         - "8000:8000"
       depends_on:
         - db
       stdin_open: true
       tty: true
   ```

Also, you can read postgres image [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)  about storing data. Especially: "Where to Store Data" chapter

Comment: that does seem to be a step in the right path, but after making these changes I am unable to `runserver`. I get the following exception: `could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`
So I'm guessing I should update `settings.py` as well? Should I remove `db` from `HOST`?

Comment: hmm... location of database should not make difference for django. Lets try something less complicated. Expose default database location in container to host. I edited answer above

Comment: That does seem to work! I have the posgres files in /var/lib/postgresql/data and adding packages to requirements.txt does not recreate the database.
One last question if you can - a local directory `database` was created as expected. Shouldn't it contain the postgres files as in /var/lib/postgresql/data? It is empy..

Comment: @Derorrist It should, but I think you need root privileges to see files (docker daemon is running as a root). Try to log as root: `sudo -i`, then check again.

Comment: Well I'm working on Windows Docker, so it might be something else. I saw a few articles on this bug. Anyway thanks for the help!